# How to run queries in Google App Engine datastore UI

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to run queries on the local GAE datastore through the UI that runs on localhost:8000, when I execute `dev_appserver.py`. There is a data "viewer" at localhost:8000/datastore, which lets me page through data, but that is not useful for debugging if you have hundreds+ rows.

Comment: Correct, and its not loading your code so it is only useful cursory examination.  Use remote api shell to connect to the dev server, or write some tests yourself.

Comment: In addition in the datastore viewer you can click on options and enter GQL statements, but not in dev.